# Multiplication operator is not jointly continuous in strong topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

How can I show that multiplication operator ($M:\mathcal{L}(X,Y) \times \mathcal{L}(Y,Z) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(X,Z)$; $M(A,B)=AB)$ is not jointly continuous in strong topology?

I have to show that if I take an open set $O$ in $\mathcal{L}(X,Z)$ (with norm topology) then $M^{-1}O$ is not always an open set in $\mathcal{L}(X,Y) \times \mathcal{L}(Y,Z)$ with the strong topology. Right? But How!?

Thank you!

Comment: this property suprises me... my first guess: that might have something to do with the product topology. And also with the spaces: with $X=Y=Z=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}\right)=\mathbb{R}$ i think it is continuous or am I wrong?

Comment: I've found this question in many books and is very often left as exercise... other times the answer is simply "Take the shift operator." But I can't figure why...

Comment: sorry I forgot to write the adjective "jointly". Now it's edited

Comment: @Max For finite-dimensional spaces, all Hausdorff vector space topologies coincide, and all multilinear maps are continuous. One needs infinite-dimensional spaces for it to be discontinuous.

Comment: Please, let me "see" it!

Comment: What I write down here is not my own, I just copy pasted from Wiki (with minimal edits) so you can see it immediatley. On wiki there is also some more information.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_operator_topology#Other_properties

Let $T$ be the unilateral shift, $T_{n}:=T^{n}$. Appealing to Cauchy-Schwarz, one has that both $T_{n}$ and $T_{n}^{*}$ converges to $0$ in WOT. But $T_{n}^{*}T_{n}$ is the identity operator for all $n$.

---

Edit:

- Since this applies only to weak operator topology I'm not sure if the hint "shift operator" helps.

Comment: page 18 of http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matwml/Research_Materials/Operator%20Algebras/Roe.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us show that if $Y$ is infinite-dimensional, then multiplication is not jointly continuous on $\mathcal L(X,Y)\times \mathcal L(Y,Z)$ with respect to the strong operator topology.

Choose any non-zero $x_0\in X$. It is enough to show that the set 
$\mathcal M:=\{ (A,B);\; \Vert BAx_0\Vert <1\} $
is not an $SOT\times SOT$-neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ in $\mathcal L(X,Y)\times \mathcal L(Y,Z)$. Equivalently, let us show that for any neighbourhood $\mathcal U$ of $(0,0)$, one can find $(A,B)\in\mathcal U$ such that $\Vert BA x_0\Vert\geq 1$.

Choose $\varepsilon >0$ and finite sets $E\subset X$ and $F\subset Y$ such that
$$\Bigl(\Vert Au\Vert<\varepsilon\;\hbox{for all $u\in F$ and}\; \Vert Bv\Vert<\varepsilon\;\hbox{for all $v\in F$}\Bigr)\implies (A,B)\in\mathcal U\, . $$

Since $\dim(Y)=\infty$, one can find an operator $A\in\mathcal L(X,Y)$ such that $y_0:=Ax_0\not\in \hbox{span}(F)$. Moreover, multiplying $A$ by a suitable constant, we may assume that $\Vert A\Vert$ is arbitrarily small, so that in particular $\Vert Au\Vert<\varepsilon$ for all $u\in E$.

Next, since $y_0\not\in \hbox{span}(F)$, one can find an operator $B\in\mathcal L(Y,Z)$ such that $B\equiv 0$ on $F$ and $By_0\neq 0$; and multiplying $B$ by a suitable constant we may assume that $\Vert By_0\Vert=1$.

By the definition of $A$ and $B$, we then have $(A,B)\in\mathcal U$ and $\Vert BAx_0\Vert=\Vert By_0\Vert=1$, which concludes the proof.

Note however that multiplication *is* jointly continuous on bounded sets. (This is not difficult to prove). Hence, by the Uniform Boundedness Principle (assuming that $X,Y,Z$ are Banach spaces) it is not possible to find two *sequences* $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ such that $A_n\xrightarrow{SOT} 0$ and $B_n\xrightarrow{SOT} 0$ but $B_nA_n$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: Could you explain more about why the multiplication is jointly continuous on bounded sets? I tried to show myself but it seems much trickier than expected... I cannot figure out at all where the boundedness comes in....

Comment: @Keith Take a bounded net $(A_i,B_i)$ converging to $(A,B)$. Then, for any $x$, you have  $\Vert A_iB_i x-ABx\Vert \leq \Vert A_i\Vert \Vert B_ix-Bx\Vert + \Vert A_i Bx-ABx\Vert\leq M\Vert B_ix-Bx\Vert +\Vert (A_i-A) Bx\Vert$ for some constant $M$; so $A_iB_ix\to ABx$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a natural example in the case of a Hilbert space.

if $H$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$, it is not hard to show that there is a net $\{n_\alpha\}$ of positive integers such that $\{\sqrt{n_\alpha}\,e_{n_\alpha}\}_\alpha$ converges weakly to $0$.

Let $T_\alpha\in B(H)$ be the rank-one operator
$$
T_\alpha\,x=\sqrt{n_\alpha}\,\langle x,e_{n_\alpha}\rangle\,e_{n_\alpha}.
$$
Then
$$
\|T_\alpha\,x\|=|\sqrt{n_\alpha}\,\langle x,e_{n_\alpha}\rangle|\to0.
$$
That is, $T_\alpha\xrightarrow{\rm sot}0$. We will see, however, that $\{T_j^2\}$ does not converges sot to $0$.

We easily see that
$$
\|T_\alpha^2\,x\|=|{n_\alpha}\,\langle x,e_{n_\alpha}\rangle|.
$$
If $T_\alpha^2\xrightarrow{\rm sot}0$, this would imply that $0$ is in the weak closure of $\{ne_n\}$, which is a contradiction. To see the contradiction, consider the weak neighbourhood of $0$ given by $V=\{y:\ |\langle x,y\rangle|<1\}$, where
$$
y=\sum_n\frac1n\,e_n. 
$$
Then
$$
\langle ne_n,y\rangle=1,\qquad\qquad n\in\mathbb N, 
$$
and so $V\cap \overline{\{ne_n\}}^{w}=\emptyset$, implying that $0\not\in\overline{\{ne_n\}}^{w}$.